# Writing nlog output to a Storage Table (custom target)

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-table-storage

I am trying to write the output of nlog to a storage table. I am also printing it on the console, which works fine. However, the table doesn't get created where I want the logging output.

Below is my app.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"    />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="value" />
  </appSettings>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NLog" publicKeyToken="5120e14c03d0593c" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

nlog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd">
  <targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="Console output: Debug Error caught"  />
    <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog"  log="Application"  />
  </targets>
 <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="console" />
    <logger name="*" levels="Error,Fatal,Warn" writeTo="eventlog" />
 </rules>
</nlog>
```

Class Program:

```cs
 class Program
{
   private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets
                           .RegisterDefinition("MyFirst", typeof(MyNamespace.MyFirstTarget));
        try
        {
            logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
            logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
            logger.Info("Sample informational message");
            logger.Warn("Sample warning message");
            logger.Error("Sample error message");
            logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Custom target Class:

```cs
[Target("MyFirst")]
public sealed class MyFirstTarget : TargetWithLayout
{
    public MyFirstTarget()
    {

    }
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        string logMessage = this.Layout.Render(logEvent);
        if (logEvent.Parameters != null && logEvent.Parameters.Count() > 1)
            SendTheMessageToRemoteHost(logEvent.Parameters[0] as string, logEvent.Message);
    }
    private void SendTheMessageToRemoteHost(string id, string body)
    {
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("SampleLogTable2");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();
        LogEntry le = new LogEntry();
        le.Message = body;
        le.id = id;
        TableOperation insert = TableOperation.Insert(le);
        table.Execute(insert);
    }
}
```

The storage table class:

```cs
public class LogEntry : TableEntity
{
    public LogEntry()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        PartitionKey = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}", now);
        RowKey = string.Format("{0:dd HH:mm:ss.fff}-{1}", now, Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    #region Table columns 
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string LoggerName { get; set; }
    public string RoleInstance { get; set; }
    public string DeploymentId { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    #endregion

     }
}
```

The couput appears on the console. [image]

However, the storage table (custom target) doesn't reach.

Comment: nlog target does not seem to have value for azure table storage.. https://github.com/harouny/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage

Comment: When having problems like this, log to the `InternalLog`, or try to debug your own target